# Error while drawing kivy rectangle using canvas

Tags: python, kivy

I need some help with kivy,i am pretty new to kivy and I made a class to to draw a rectangle as a background.
I am pretty sure I did everything correctly but there is an error,so here is my code
**The .py file**

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class Background(Widget):
    pass

class MY_browser(App):
    def build(self):
        return Background
        
        
MY_browser().run()
```

**The .kv file**

```
Floatlayout:
            Background:
                canvas.before:
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
```

I have tried a lot of things but no difference so if anyone can help I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple problems:

- In your `build()` method, the `return Background` is returning a class, but the `build()` method is expected to return a `Widget` instance. Perhaps this should be `return Background()`.
- In your `kv`, the indentation is incorrect. All indentations should be a multiple of the same number of spaces (typically 4). The indentation of `Background` is too large.
- Your `kv` does not provide a rule for `Background`, so when `Background()` is returned, it will simply be an empty `Widget`. If you want to `return Background()`, you should have a `<Background>:` rule in the `kv`.
- If your `kv` file is named `my_browser.kv`, then you do not need a `build()` method for your `App` class at all.
- If your `kv` file is not named as above, then your build method can be `return Builder.load_file("kv file name")`, where `kv file name` is replaced by the correct name of your `kv` file.
- The `Floatlayout` in your `kv` is misspelled. It should be `FloatLayout`.